# Position: Fixed property not working on small screens

Tags: html, css

I have to divs, one fixed at the top, and other fixed at the bottom.

They are fixed at large screens (Computers) but not in small screens (Mobiles).

My CSS:

```
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 0;
}
```

Visit [website](http://whspr.epizy.com) for demo!

Comment: Please share a minimal working copy of your HTML and CSS and explain the problem more thoroughly. Sharing your website is not enough research.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check in mobile view in desktop is also not fixed because of css define in bootstrap responsive css

Just update below css in your code:

```
@media (max-width: 979px)
   .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
       position: fixed;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple (In your media query)

```
media query@media (max-width: 979px)
bootstrap-responsive.min.css:9 .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom { position: static; }
```

Replace `position:static` with `position:fixed`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your body has a padding on smaller screen devices and that's what is causing the issue, not the fixed positioning itself.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the downvotes on all the answers?

Answer (score -1):

That´s because this style

[image: mediaquerie]

It changes the attribute of navbar to static on screens with 979px or less